# LWJGL GLSL Shader validity check always fails, though shader works fine

Tags: java, opengl, graphics, opengl-es, lwjgl

I have a function that checks whether or not the vertex/fragment shared was compiled successfully and is valid to use within LWJGL

```
public static boolean isShaderValid(int shaderToCheck) {
    IntBuffer iVal = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(1);
    glGetObjectParameterARB(shaderToCheck, GL_OBJECT_INFO_LOG_LENGTH_ARB, iVal);
    int length = iVal.get();
    boolean isValid = length>1;
    if (isValid && verboseValidityCheck) {
        printShaderLogInfo(shaderToCheck, iVal, length);
    }
    return isValid;
}
```

This however, ALWAYS returns false, even though when I skip this check and just use the shader, it works fine. So, what is wrong with this shader validity check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not appropriate to use the infolog length to check the validity of a shader.

I'm not sure if you're referring to a **program** or a **shader** here, but you should call [glGetProgramiv](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetProgram.xml) or [glGetShaderiv](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetShader.xml) with GL_LINK_STATUS/GL_COMPILE_STATUS respectively to get a boolean pass/fail result.

The info log length is only useful when you want to allocate a buffer of chars to retrieve the log, and the contents of the log are completely up to the GPU vendor and arbitrary.

It could easily return `"Compile Successful"` in the infolog after shader compilation, which would make your length check to be useless.

Answer (score 1):

This part

boolean isValid = length>1;

will get you a False value for any empty Info Log.

An empty Info Log for a shader is fine as far as I know, so could get a False result with any perfectly validating shader.